# Calculate parameters of 2DOF mass spring damper system at steady state

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

I am given a task and I actually have answers. I think I know the way how it was solved, but I cannot understand why it is done like this.
Task sounds as follows:
Consider the below system configured parallel to the gravitational field and constrained to move only in the vertical direction and with all four components connected to each other. The gravity is .
[image]

In the initial state the depicted system is at rest and the spring has its nominal length, i.e. there is no force in the spring. The spring and the damper are linear and without constraints, i.e. they have unlimited motion range. Suddenly the two supports for the masses are instantly removed. Answer the below questions for the situation that the system has reached steady-state. Express the respective answers as functions of a selection of the variables/parameters , , , N  9.
Note that you do not have to derive a complete model of the system. The answers can be found by knowing the constitutive equations and energy properties of the components combined with some reasoning

a) What is the velocity of $_2$?

Solution: $m_2 * g/d$

b) What is the position of $_1$?

Solution: $(m_1 + m_2)g/k$

c) If there is power dissipation, where is it and how large is it?

Solution: In the damper $ P = \frac{m_2^2 * g^2}{d}$

d) If there is energy stored, where is it and how large is it?

Solution: In the spring, $E_s = \frac 12 kx_1^2 = \frac {(m_1+m_2)^2g^2}{2k}$ and in the mass 2, $E_m = \frac 12 m_2v_2^2 = \frac {m_2^3g^2}{2d^2}$

After creating free body diagrams I derived differential equation for mass 1:
$$ -kx_1 - d(\dot x_2 - \dot x_1) + m_1g + m_2g = m_1 \ddot x_1$$
Same for mass 2:
$$ -d(\dot x_2 - \dot x_1) + m_2g = m_2 \ddot x_2 $$

For question A:

I decided that $m_2 \ddot x_2 = 0$ because system is at steady state, is not moving, acceleration is $0$
I derived answer from differential equation for mass 2
$$ \dot x_2 = \frac {m_2g + \ddot x_1}{d} $$
Final answer: $$ \dot x_2 = \frac {m_2g + d \dot x_1}{d}$$
I see that it is almost the same as the given answer, if I decide that $\dot x_1 = 0$, because system is at steady state, I would receive same answer, but if $\dot x_1 = 0$ I would guess that $\dot x_2$ should also be $0$ and the answer to whole question is $0$. Why only $\dot x_1 = 0$?

For question B:

Again, answer derived from differential equations with $m_1 \ddot x_1 = 0$:
$$x_1 = \frac {(m_1 + m_2)g - d(\dot x_2 - \dot x_1)}{k}$$
And if we assume $\dot x_2 = 0$ and $\dot x_1 = 0$, answer is the same as given:
$$ x_1 = \frac {(m_1 + m_2)g}{k}$$
Which looks logical that if acceleration is zero, velocity is also zero, but it is not the same in question A?

For questions C:

Calculating dissipated power through formula
$$ P = dv^2 = d(\dot x_2 - \dot x_1)^2 $$
Now assuming $\dot x_1 = 0$ and plugging in answer from question A (again same question as in question A, why?). I received an answer:
$$ P = \frac {m_2^2g_2^2}{d} $$
Which is same as given

For question D:

At first it seems logical to calculate energy stored in spring
$$ E_1 = \frac 12 kx_1^2$$
And plugging in answer from question B
$$ E = \frac {(m_1 + m_2)^2g^2}{2k} $$

But in the answer also energy stored in mass 2 is calculated
$$ E = \frac 12 m_2 \dot x_2^2 $$
Plugging in answer from question A
$$ E = \frac {m_2^3g^2}{2d_2}$$

But then, why aren't energy stored in mass 1 calculated? And same question as in question A, if system at steady state, aren't velocity and acceleration supposed to be $0$ for mass 2?

Comment: Steady state does not mean motionless here. Try solving the simpler problem of a single mass hanging from a damper. What is its steady state? Recall that the ideal damper is assumed to be able to extend indefinitely.

Comment: Okay, now I looked at definition of steady state once more and I see that states of the system should be unchanging. In order for them to be unchanging, acceleration is zero. Motion of mass 1 is  zero, because force exerted by the spring depends on distance, so it reached equilibrium with gravity. But velocity of mass 2 is not zero, because force exerted by damper depends on the velocity, so in order for it to reach equilibrium with gravity it should be at constant speed and that's where its ability to extend indefinitely comes in place. Am I right?

Comment: Yes; hopefully this resolves the related questions.

Comment: But why in question B, I need to assume both $\dot x_1$ and $\dot x_2$ equal to zero, but in question A I've calculated $\dot x_2$ it is not zero. If I plug answer from A to B, without assuming $\dot x_2 = 0$ I don't get required answer. I cannot wrap my head around it

Comment: Your equilibrium equations are incorrect (possibly because of incorrect free-body diagrams). Mass 1 should be subjected to the damper force but not the direct weight of mass 2. And I see at least one incorrect sign.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the explanation in the comments, I got it. I will repost my understanding as an answer:

I looked at the definition of steady state once more, and I see that the states of the system should be unchanging. To this end, the accelerations should be zero. Mass 1 is immobile because the force exerted by the spring depends on distance, so the mass reaches equilibrium with gravity. But the velocity of mass 2 is not zero because the force exerted by the damper depends on this velocity, so for mass 2 to reach equilibrium with gravity, it should fall at a constant speed, and that's where the damper's ability to extend indefinitely comes in.